# Is there any automated way I can detect if a co-author plagiarized before our paper is submitted?

Tags: publications, plagiarism, software

My professor, a co-author and I have been working on a paper for more than a year. I was doing the math and simulations, my co-author was responsible for the writing, and my professor was editing the paper. Now editing of the paper is done. Unfortunately, the co-author is no longer available. My professor called me today and told me he has observed that my co-author copied some sentences from the reference papers. So he asked me to check all of the sentences and highlight and rewrite them again if I found that they were copied. He believes that, these days the reviewers are more concerned about the use of similar sentences in the paper.

So, What should I do? Check all sentences with other papers? This is not possible without using a machine. the paper contains more than 8000 words. Do you know what software I can use to do this?

Comment: Copying a sentence (or more) from another paper is not plagiarism provided the material copied is enclosed in quotes (or indented if a large block) and properly cited.  Is that the case?  Or are the copied sentences presented as though the three of you had written them?

Comment: The copied sentences are not enclosed in quotes. Some of them are cited but some not. Actually the content and our method is new. But some explanations and sentences are copy paste. @BobBrown

Comment: I guess you want something like the reverse of diff for two very different files. I have no idea how well this works, but WCopyfind seems to do just that: http://plagiarism.bloomfieldmedia.com/z-wordpress/software/wcopyfind/ Here's what they say in the instructions: *WCopyfind compares text or word processor documents with one another to determine if they share words in phrases. WCopyfind reads .DOCX, .TXT, and .HTML files natively and it does a pretty good job of reading .PDF files, as long as they contain text content rather than pure image content.*

Comment: I have heard about these software. They don't work well for my case. These software check the text line by line.So, this wont help me much. But I think, Journals check the plagiarism themselves(they warn about cross ref and cross check). so they should have a software to do it. I was wonder if I could check this matter before they check it for me . @YuichiroFujiwara

Comment: @Electricman The description of the software on the official page and blog posts from users seem to suggest this particular one does much more than typical line-by-line comparison, though. It looks like it detects identical strings of words/phrases of which you can determine parameters like length. But if you tried it and think it's the same as line-by-line comparison, I guess I was wrong; I've never used it myself. BTW, services like CrossRef are usually for publishers; such a large automated checking needs access to tons of copyrighted papers.

Comment: Anyway, if what you want to do isn't locating a string of words in document A which also appears in document B, what exactly do you want to do? I thought this was basically what CrossCheck was doing...

Comment: Okay @YuichiroFujiwara I will give it a try and tell u about the progress. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft the titular question is clearly a shopping list, but the final "paragraph" asks a reasonable question of what should I do.

Comment: @Electricman In line with StrongBad's comment, I have changed the title of this question. I believe this is in line with what your intent but please roll back my changes if I am wrong.

Comment: The title is fine and clear.  thanks @earthling

Comment: The software Wcopyfind didn't help. I also tried some other softwares too. But the results were poor. @YuichiroFujiwara

Comment: @Electricman That sucks. Sorry to hear that. Seems like you need to get a hold of the co-author or go the complete rewrite rout, which, while not related to what you asked, is probably a much better option in the first place...

Comment: No problem. What do you think about using `turnitin`? It has been suggested here from a guy. I googled and it seems Elsevier(where I want to submit) uses `turnitin` for crosscheck. @YuichiroFujiwara

Comment: @Electricman I would guess it wouldn't work very well. It's for undergrads' essays and such. It may be good if you want to check if your student copy-pasted a wikipedia article, blog post and the like, but I'm not sure if its data include enough academic papers. In your case, you sort of know where your co-author copied text from, and it's not from where undergrads typically copy-and-paste. You may miss plagiarized text if you only compare your manuscript against Turnitin's data, which is a big problem.

Comment: It seems your guess is not correct. the part you said `It may be good if you want to check if your student copy-pasted a wikipedia article, blog post and the like, but I'm not sure if its data include enough academic papers` Please see the TurnItIn FAQ here : http://turnitin.com/en_us/features/faqs
Answer of Q 2 says: `For example, Turnitin partner CrossRef boasts 500‐plus members that include publishers such as Elsevier and the IEEE, and has already added hundreds of millions of pages of new content to our database.`Really sounds like nightmare @YuichiroFujiwara

Comment: "Unfortunately, the co-author is no longer available." Do you mean that he died?  If not, how can someone be unavailable in 2015?  Anyway, a division of labor in which the person who is "responsible for the writing" is unavailable is a very poor idea.  Also: isn't fixing problems with the writing called...**editing**? If the professor puts this on you, I am concerned that he is not contributing enough to the paper.  Anyway, I agree with everyone else: it sounds like you are the one who cares about this paper enough to do it right.  So do it right...and choose better coauthors next time.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark . My co-author went to the mandatory military service so he is not available at this project any more. Also, I fixed that plagiarism problem by completely rewriting the paper while ago. But my professor and I observed some numerical manipulation which was done from the left co-author as he was responsible for part of the Matlab programming. Now I am sucked at it to fix this problem for few month. My professor doesn't help me with Matalb programing of the problem and just gives me intuitive math descriptions. :(

Answer (score 13):

I am both confused and concerned about the description of your work process:

> I was doing the math and simulations, my co-author was taking the care of writing and my professor was editing the paper.

It seems clear you are making a contribution worthy of authorship, but as for your "co-author" and professor, it is not clear if their contributions are worthy of authorship. the fact that the co-author is unavailable make the situation difficult. High end plagiarism detection software is still not particularly good and I would be hesitant about using any work written by someone who is known to have plagiarised in the past, especially in the absence of drafts to confirm the absence of plagiarism.

The issue with using software like TurnItIn is not its abilitity to detect and parse copied material, but the limitations on its underlying database. Plagiarism detection software generally does not have access to non-open access publications. If your co-author copied from non-open access publications, then the software will likely miss it. A publishers, like elsivier Edith a large amount of pay walled material may add their own publications to their database making it easy for them to catch the plagiarism.

My suggestion would be to rewrite all the material by the co-author. You could either work from his version and maintain his authorship, or if his only contribution was the writing as you say, then rewrite those sections from scratch and drop him from the list of authors.

Comment: It takes a lot of time and energy to rewrite the paper. @strongbad

Comment: @Electricman It all really depends on how much you care about quality. If you want to be sure and you can't trust your co-author (and I agree with StrongBad here, don't share authorship with others who have plagiarized in the past), then you need to re-write it. The time and energy is the cost of choosing your co-author poorly. Bad decisions have consequences.

Comment: @Electricman: It may take a long time to rewrite the paper, but it will be more damaging to you if the paper is retracted for plagiarism!

Comment: It is a good tip to know, So `TurnItIn` cannot detect the plagiarism from non-open access papers. Well I know where my co-author copied from. We have 30 references in this paper and he modified some sentences mostly in the introduction and problem description parts to make the writing easier. So, I should read all 30 refs and compare it with our manuscript. sounds like a big effort but easier than re-writing the whole piece. @strongbad

Comment: @Electricman NO! That is not what my answer is saying. If you go looking for all the copied material and you miss just one occurrence, your reputation will take a big hit. It might be easier, but it is not worth the risk.

Comment: It seems your answer is not completely correct. the part you said `Plagiarism detection software generally does not have access to non-open access publications. If your co-author copied from non-open access publications, then the software will likely miss it.` Please see the TurnItIn FAQ here : http://turnitin.com/en_us/features/faqs
Answer of Q 2 says: `For example, Turnitin partner CrossRef boasts 500‐plus members that include publishers such as Elsevier and the IEEE, and has already added hundreds of millions of pages of new content to our database.`Really sounds like nightmare @StrongBad

Comment: I don't understand your adversion against rewriting it. What is more important? Your future career or making this assignment as easy as possible? Rewriting is the only sure way you have, anything else might still bear a risk, as small as it is, but if anything goes wrong, your reputation is terminally ruined. And 8'000 words is a small thing. My current manuscript (book) is now on 90'000 and not done yet.

Comment: @Electricman some content published by Elsevier and IEEE are open access. My experience looking at similarity reports is that TurnItIn does not have access to all of Elsevier's journals.

Comment: Thanks for your information. None of our references are available for open access. And I know that my co-author only changed some sentences of our references. I've tried to find them manually but it was not possible. So in line with your suggestion I am going to re-write the whole manuscript :((( @StrongBad

Comment: I am going to re-write it :(( @PatricHartmann

Comment: @Electricman: Believe me, it's the best choice. The damage plagiarism, even just accidental, can do to your career justifies the additional workload.

Answer (score 4):

Your institution may use a standard service which you would have access to - you could contact your academic admin service and ask them.  "Turnitin" seems quite widely used.

Comment: unfortunately they do not have it. Also, I am graduated few month ago. @jool

Comment: @Electricman You can still use [TurnItIn's product for students](http://en.writecheck.com/).

Comment: I wish you could recommended something free @earthling

Comment: @Electricman The free stuff is garbage. "You get what you pay for" is so very true in the world of plagiarism checking.

Comment: That is really true, but not only for the world of plagiarism checking. I should find someone who has turnitin, maybe some universities have it already for their students @earthling

Comment: Your Prof. should know if there is an auto-checking service available and would presumably have access to it.  Failing that, how about your co-author?

Comment: Unfortunately my Prof doesn't know. I asked people from other universities and they don't use Turnitin at their university too. I think it's bx, our subjects are not taught in English here so the assignments are not in English as well and Turnitin cannot detect plagiarism for non-English  manuscripts. @Jool

Answer (score 3):

While [TurnItIn](http://turnitin.com/) is designed for undergraduate assignments, [iThenticate](http://www.ithenticate.com/) is designed for this exact scenario: detecting plagiarism in academic publications. I've used it successfully in the past, and while it is not cheap you can purchase a license to check a single document at a time.

Comment: I have written the paper again as this question was posted before your answer. Thank you for your helpful answer. If next time it comes up I will use that. @corvus